# I am studying for a test and I got stuck on this proablity problem.

Tags: probability

Let X1,X2,...Xn be a random sample from an exponential distribution with $\beta$ > 0 unknown

a. Find MLE of $\beta$ (Not Sure how to get Started)

b.Another estimator of $\beta$ is $\tilde{\beta}$= X1 is it better than the MLE? use the MSE to answer the question (same as above

c.The MLE of $\beta^3$ is $\bar{X}^3$. What is the limiting distribution of the MLE?

(on part (c.) i was able to figure out that i will have to use Fisher information and CRLB)

Comment: I have a feeling that this question is going to be downvoted because you didn't show effort. What have you tried? What do you already know about the problem? What do you think you need to use but are unable to use? Where are you stuck? etc.

Comment: i know on part c i have to use Fisher information and CRLB.

Comment: Then you should have added that to your post, as well as all other thoughts and tell exactly what you don't know.

Comment: I see nobody is answering yet. I guess that's because you need to follow @Pedro's advice, and also because (a) and (b) are very standard problems on MLE. Seconds ago my Google search on 'mle exponential' returned many links, the 1st 4 of them directly relevant. For (a) you need to maximize the likelihood or (often more conveniently) the log likelihood function. Specifically, maybe see Wikipedia under Parameter Estimation. (b) Just from common sense, which do you think is better: a single observation or information from the entire sample summarized as an MLE? What is the criterion for 'better'?